# EmberJS (without ember-cli) development behind firewall using systemjs or any other loader

Tags: ember.js

I am planning to use EmberJS for a small application in my day job. I have used a little ember on my  laptop using ember-cli. However at work I don't have access to Github.
I am planning to download the libraries and start using without any tools like npm, bower. I have tried to setup a static web app at https://github.com/mmrath/ember-standalone 
There is not much code in there. I have tried to keep the structure as close to ember-cli as possible, os that it will be easier for me to upgrade to ember-cli when access is available. I would like to use ES6 modules like in ember-cli. However the fist step of loading the Ember is not working.

Error I see in chrome console is

> Error: http://localhost:4200/vendor/ember/ember.debug.js detected as System.register but didn't execute.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how you don't have access to bower and npm? Is this by company policy that you just can't use it or the service is blocked by firewall?